# Which anaconda related websites are official and which ones are 3rd party?

Tags: anaconda, conda

New to Anaconda and following a tutorial. I see that there is
Anaconda dot com, anaconda dot org, and conda dot io.

I have in the past seen instances where unofficial sources and pages for a result were higher ranked on Google for strange reasons.

Which of these websites do I go to and are all three of these legit?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the above mentioned websites belong to Anaconda Inc.